# Problem with iteration in a for loop that contains if statement

Tags: python, loops, matlab, if-statement, iteration

I am new in programming and I have to admit very ignorant.

I am currently trying to transform a Matlab script to Python but I face some issues. What I need is to select values of an existing array, based on a threshold, and create a new list. The threshold is a set value that the result of a subtraction between the i+1 and i elements of my array should not cross. If the threshold is crossed I want to keep the first value (i.e i+1).

Here is the Matlab code of reference:

```matlab
    old_list = [10; 32; 35; 60; 90; 100];      
    doube_indices = [];    
    for i=1:length(old_list)-1
        if(old_list(i+1) - old_list(i) < threshold)
            doube_indices = [doube_indices i+1];
        end
    end
    new_list(doube_indices) = [];
    threshold = 20;
```

I tried to make something similar in Python in several ways but I am constantly failing. I believe my biggest problem is to select the second number of the list as it is done in MATLAB i.e. i+1. It might be something very easy but I am too new on that stuff so I would appreciate some input! Could you please help me?

Comment: That last line, `new_list(doube_indices) = [];` requires `new_list` to be initialized, I think. What is its value? And how come `threshold` is defined after it’s used? I don’t think this is a [mre]!

Comment: Oh sorry you are right, the threshold is misplaced in the end instead of the top. Similarly I missed the initiation of the list new_list above the doube_indices definition. I would have been new_list = old_list ... Sorry again!

Answer (score 1):

One key difficulty is that Python numbers its lists starting from 0, whereas Matlab starts at 1.  This implements your basic code:

```
old_list = [10, 32, 35, 60, 90, 100]
threshold = 20
double_indices = []
for i in range(len(old_list)-1):
    if old_list[i+1] - old_list[i] < threshold:
        double_indices.append(i+1)
print(double_indices)
```

Output:

```
[2, 5]
```

As you get more sophisticated, you'll want to start using the `numpy` library.  `numpy` implements most of what MATLAB can do, allowing you to operate on an entire array or array slice at a time.

### Followup

If you just want the values from the old list that are not close to the previous element, that's a different loop:

```
old_list = [10, 32, 35, 60, 90, 100]
threshold = 20
new_list = []
for val in old_list:
    if not new_list or abs(val - new_list[-1]) > threshold:
        new_list.append(val)
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[10, 32, 60, 90]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  This will indeed give me the correct indices I need from the old list but I am now wondering how I can use it to create a new_list similarly to the matlab code new_list(doube_indices) = [];

Comment: Update: I found a way using new_list = [old_list[i] for i in double_indices] but this gives me the values of the double indices. What I am now trying is to have a new list based on the old one but without the numbers on the double indices...

Comment: What??  You specifically said you wanted indexes.  Are you now saying you want a new list, which has all items from the old list that are not close to the one before?  That's easy, but that's a different problem.

Comment: Sorry I meant I wanted the values based on the correct indices. I combined your  first comment to get it and it worked: old_list = [10, 32, 35, 60, 90, 100]
threshold = 20
double_indices = []
for i in range(len(old_list)-1):
    if old_list[i+1] - old_list[i] < threshold:
        double_indices.append(i+1) # with this threshold you should have i2=35 and i5=100 that need to be removed from the old list'''
list_indices = [old_list[i] for i in double_indices] # this gives me the values of the double indices
new_list = [x for x in old_list if x not in list_indices] # this is the final list

Comment: Your new comment is way more efficient though thank you so much!